# How do you count months of work experience on resume?

Tags: resume, united-states

If I list that I worked from 1/2020-7/2020: will the HR person count this as 6 or 7 months of experience?
So:

- is the month of July counted as a full month worked (and so the HR person counts 7 months work experience)
  OR
- it is assumed this stops at July 1 -- and so it means you have 6 months experience.

Comment: If it is important to you that your experience be perceived correctly, you should put in the start and stop days, not just the month.

Comment: At the very least, this needs a location. In the UK, this is "less than a year" and pretty much equivalent to "zero experience" anyway.

Comment: thank you. From the USA. I have short-term jobs/contracts, so whether a month counts or not is important.
Thanks!

Comment: When the period is so short, they're going to write a question mark next to the dates and ask more questions. Either that, or they'll just put your resume at the bottom of the pile and not even bother about the questions. In any case, apply to everything you can. Even if it says one or two years experience required, apply anyway. If you wait until you meet all the criteria on a job posting, it's never going to happen.

Answer (score 5):

You haven't specified your location, so I'll answer from my own perspective of the UK.

Recruiters don't look at work experience at that level of detail. To a recruiter, 6 months experience and 7 months experience are equivalent.

If you have multiple short-term contracts, then you can add a summary of the total experience in technologies relevant to the job you are applying for (tailor the summary based on the requirements in the job advert).

When job adverts include requirements for experience, the purpose is to give an idea of the rough seniority of the role. They don't expect candidates to have everything that they are asking for, even experience that is listed as required.

The exception to this is if the job advert specifies "min 1 year commercial experience" for example, **and** they get so many applicants that it would take too long to read their CVs properly. In this scenario if you don't clearly demonstrate the requirement then your CV could be filtered out. If you had 10 months experience, then you could round that up to 1 year in a covering letter. Your CV should include the actual dates.